# What to do with random pages after a 301 redirect?

Tags: seo, http-status-code-301

I did a standard 301 redirect for a domain, but the original domain has about 300 pages that have some strength.

It doesn't make sense to make them all point back to the new home page because the individual pages are about some topics.

Also, there aren't the same pages in the new domain, so where should the original random pages redirect to?  I would like to have them rank for the same topics they used to, but without having the original domain giving them strength, they will just stop ranking and die off.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 300 pages of the same topic, redirect the old pages 1:1 to the new pages.

Also, go to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ and ask the question there, as this is not really programming related.

Comment: True, but won't these old pages slowly lose their strengths?  They were mostly getting strength from the domain which is now redirected to a new place.

Comment: well, if you redirect all the old pages to the new pages the value of the old site (a site is just a collection of pages) passes, too. anyway it is only worth it if the old pages have some very very old and valuable incoming links, otherwise do not bother and do something else useful with your time. there are so much opportunities i would not waste to much energy on old 2 new migration just because of some previous existing ranking performance.